# I need help compiling libcurl as static with no dependencies

Tags: c++, c, curl, mingw, libcurl

For the past week I have been trying to get libcurl to run as static using pre built packages but they require libcurl's dependencies, which I don't have. All of the dependencies don't have any pre built packages so I would have to compile every single one from source, and I have never compiled a library before. I don't need libcurls dependencies in the first place because I am only using curl for http requests.

So I was wondering if it's possible to compile libcurl as a static library which has no dependencies with mingw for win32. I have never built a library from source before but this is my last resort because I cannot find anything online explaining how to do this.

Comment: Maybe you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774103/using-an-embedded-dll-in-an-executable)

Comment: 6800+ Q/A when you search for `compile static [c]`. In any case, we can't help you if you won't include your code (Makefile, or `gcc` cmd-line). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I have no code to show cause I have no idea what I'm doing, that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: What is your overall project that requires `libcurl`?

Comment: @shellter Well I am trying to get a string from a website which only has one line of text. Something like this www.icanhazip.com. This can be done with libcurl easy with only a couple lines of code.

Comment: ok, and you want it to run "stand-alone" on a Windows machine or ?

Comment: and sorry, but I am busy today, so won't be able to "talk" with you. What is your timezone? I am CST. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, windows 32bit

Comment: and I'm eastern standard time

Comment: So I still don't understand what is unique about your project that you can't just use `curl.exe` wrapped in some scripts (or even advanced .bat file code). But let me confirm, your need is a small `c` program that is essentially a wrapper to `libcurl` and that you want it to be completely stand-alone not requiring any external .dlls or other dynamic linking, where all required dependencies should be static and "internal" to your tool? (I'll be back in a while).

Comment: @shellter Exactly, completely stand alone with no file dropping.

Comment: yes, but what is wrong with the `curl.exe`s you can download and run locally? I'll inspect mine later and see if it using an externals. TTYL

Comment: @shellter If there is no way of doing this without file dropping I will probably convert curl.exe to base64 and store it in my program and have it drop and convert on run time, but I would like to avoid that. Thank you for your help and time btw.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "file dropping" and I don't see it mentioned in your original Q. Not clear on your expertise. What sort of project is your `libcurl` wrapper intended to solve(yes, I know http requests, more specifcially, the same http request each time, or read from a list or ??). Out is used for? http requests would be the #1 use case for `curl.exe`. Have you tried solving your problem just using `curl.exe`? Did you read something about your specific problem domain that makes you think you need to use `libcurl` instead? TTYL

Comment: Get it to work anyway you can, as easily as possible and if required then optimize your project/process by adding `libcurl`. You now about `system()`? right?

Comment: @shellter What I mean by file dropping is my program creating a file. And yes it will be the same http request every time. I have not tried curl.exe yet because I want my program to have everything it needs within itself. Do you have skype or any other way of contacting you? It would be easier to explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I used to have skype, I'll have to see if it is still working. I'm going to bed soon. Are you available during the day tomorrow?

Comment: @shellter Yeah, send me a message when you can. Skype: cynoqq

Comment: ok, sounds good.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a skype acct any more. I've looked at  my  local copy of `curl.exe` it is a tangled nest of calls to windows DLLs (shared objects). I don't have the time to try and sort this out. Again, if you're thinking having an all static version of `curl` is going to be more efficient and run X% faster, I'm pretty sure this classifies as a "Premature optimization" and will not pay off in any substantial way. Good luck.

Comment: Just saw this (working on my on MSYS2 project (maybe)) "MinGW64 compilers default to linking statically, and can throw exceptions from static builds" at https://sourceforge.net/projects/cbadvanced/ IHTH

Comment: i found your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32117592/2695810